# While speedily clicking on item of gridview, same method has been called twice a time

Tags: android, gridview, onitemclicklistener, showdialog

I have used grid view in my project. When I click on grid view item speedily, it calls the same method twice a time. But I slowly click, then it works perfectly.

In method below I call the dialog box. When I click the item it opens the dialog box but when I speedily click the item then dialog box open two times. What should I do to solve this?

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {
        showDialog(position);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution for opening twice time method. I can define the below condition through solved it:

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    private long mLastClickTime = 0;

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) return;

        mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        grideProductAdd(position);          
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code which doesn't allow multiple speed clicks instead of your onclicklistener.

```
public abstract class SingleClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final long THRESHOLD_MILLIS = 500L;
    private long lastClickMillis;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        long now = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        if (now - lastClickMillis > THRESHOLD_MILLIS) {
            onClicked(v);
            lastClickMillis = 0;
        } else {
            lastClickMillis = now;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onClicked(View v);
}
```

and instead of normal onclicklistener use this

```
 stage1_nxt.setOnClickListener(new SingleClickListener() {
```

Comment: i add the method inside the if condition ?

Comment: but i have to use grid.setonitemclickListner

Comment: grid.setonitemclicklistener(new singleclicklistener)

Comment: you have to modify it to implement onitemclicklistener